# Zeppelin Internal error processing create Interpreter

Tags: apache-zeppelin, apache-phoenix

I tried to install new zeppelin i.e 0.8.0 version, I followed [this](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/setup/deployment/flink_and_spark_cluster.html) link to install zeppelin .

Since I wanted phoenix interpreter, I added interpreter with the help of guide given in [here](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/interpreter/jdbc.html).

When I run the the below paragraph I got the below error

```
%phoenix
select * from "mytable"  

org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing createInterpreter
at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_createInterpreter(RemoteInterpreterService.java:209)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.createInterpreter(RemoteInterpreterService.java:192)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter$2.call(RemoteInterpreter.java:164)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter$2.call(RemoteInterpreter.java:160)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:141)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:160)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:129)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:287)
at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:425)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:182)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I'm getting this problem now on a few interpreters that we made in house. Did you ever resolve this? If I dig into the error, it's a class not found exception so something is not right with the cp. Yet I ran jar tf <jarfile> and the class that it can't find is present.

Comment: Ok I was able to fix this. Seems like Zeppelin builds deterministic paths to the library jar using the name of your interpreter. So for example, our interpreter was named foo, and as such, I had to create a directory in Zeppelin under interpreter/foo and place the jar there that contained the interpreter class. Resolved my class not found exception and now the interpreter is working again.